# Android MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648) when referencing from string variable

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'm using jsoup to scrape some audio file source URLs and store them in a string. If the string is later not null, a button is created with an onClick listener to play that file. This has worked but in testing with different pages it has broken. If I setDatasource directly to the URL that would be scraped it works so it is not a decoder problem. Here is where the problem happens.

```
if (play1 != null) {

            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonPanel);
            final Button btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
            btn.setText("Play");
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {



                        mp.reset();
                        mp.setDataSource(play1);
                        mp.prepareAsync();
                        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.start();
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            try{
                linearLayout.addView(
                        btn,
                        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                );
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
```

If you want to recreate the problem I have included the main functionality of my project which is needed to reproduce.
 [Here](https://gist.github.com/ih8legal/a4597931aa668cb8fe8939c86d00db60) is an example of the code that works with the key variable to focus on here being the dataSource String.

And [here](https://gist.github.com/ih8legal/9cf5838fbcb7320f3c153ffb532170df) is an example of the same exact code with the only change being to the dataSource String and this one does not work.

If you want to run this code to check you will need to import the Jsoup library and also add [my checker class](https://gist.github.com/ih8legal/906d82b052b80afeeadc4b7c50f7717e).

Comment: Did you check all these google links related to the same error code? https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Android+MediaPlayer%3A+error+1%2C+2147483648

Comment: Yes I did, most are related to codec issues in earlier versions of android, nothing related to the problem that I am facing.

Comment: Give an example of play1 value that doesn't work

Comment: If you run [this](https://gist.github.com/ih8legal/9cf5838fbcb7320f3c153ffb532170df), which I have also included above you will get the error.

Comment: Can't test live right now. That's why am asking to see a play1 value that doesn't work if you run it on your side.

Comment: The weird thing is that if I change the play1 value to hold a preset string it works. Even if it were to hold the same URL that would be put there by the  scraper. But if I point it at as it is now it only works on some pages. For example [this](http://media-hearth.cursecdn.com/audio/card-sounds/sound/VO_EX1_383_Play_01.ogg) url works and [this](http://media-hearth.cursecdn.com/audio/card-sounds/sound/VO_OG_044_Male_Night%20Elf_Play_02.ogg) one does not. But this will only be apparent if you run the code live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

> mp.setDataSource(play1);

by :

> mp.setDataSource(play1.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));

Comment: This worked, could you explain what cause the error? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, idea behind is that the "%20" character is actually a space in the link that wasn't working. The goal here was then to replace all potentials 'space' characters by "%20" so that the mediaPlayer could deal properly with it

Comment: Makes sense. Hopefully the next person who has this problem will find this.